# Error 0x1c8250: double free memory in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nszombie

I am facing the error of "error for object 0x1c8250: double free" when delloc for my controller is called. I causes some memory issues. Kindly guide me about this error. What is the best thing to do to prevent this error.

Comment: Make sure you do not free the same objects more than once. It's hard to give proper advice here without seeing problematic code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076544/error-for-object-0xb50dd20-double-free)

Somewhere in your code you have a [obj release] that is incorrect.